# Why the stdscr variable does not work in PDCurses?

Tags: curses, pdcurses

My PDCurses program terminates when I pass the `stdscr` variable to any function that receives a `WINDOW*` argument (e.g., `keypad` and `wprintw`). But it works when I capture the `WINDOW*` returned by `initscr` and use it instead.

I assume that once `initscr` is called, the `WINDOW*` returned by it and the `stdscr` variable should be the same. But after comparing their addresses I realized it is not so.

I could keep using the `WINDOW*` returned by `initscr`, but that would not work in a multi-terminal program where one have to use `newterm` which returns a `SCREEN*`, not a `WINDOW*`. In that case I necessarily would need to use the `stdscr` variable, which still refuses to work.

Here is a sample code that works:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    WINDOW* wnd = initscr();
    wprintw(wnd, "Hello world!");
    refresh();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

But this one does not:

```
...
int main()
{
    initscr();
    wprintw(stdscr, "Hello world!"); // the program terminates here
    refresh();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

This potentially multi-terminal program doesn't work either:

```
...
int main()
{
    SCREEN* term = newterm(NULL, stdout, stdin);
    set_term(term);
    wprintw(stdscr, "Hello world!"); // the program terminates here
    refresh();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

So I don't know what is happening with the `stdscr` variable. I am using Windows 8.1 x64, VC++ x64 of Visual Studio 2012 and PDCurses 3.4.0.3 (downloaded with Nuget package manager).

Comment: A short sample program would help (PDCurses does return `stdscr` from `initscr`; perhaps you have declared a conflicting variable).

Comment: Thanks. I added the sample code. And yes, I mentioned that I could use the `stdscr` returned by `initscr`, but I need to know why the `stdscr` variable is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

So, referencing Git Issue #31: https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/issues/31

it looks like you probably were building without defining PDC_BUILD_DLL. As noted in win32/README (later win32/README.md, wincon/README.md):

"When you build the library as a Windows DLL, you must always define
  PDCURSES_DLL_BUILD when linking against it. (Or, if you only want to
  use the DLL, you could add this definition to your curses.h.)"

The described modification was made to the curses.h files bundled with the DLLs I distriubted on SourceForge, but not those from the NuGet project, nor apparently is the relevant documentation included in that package.

Comment: Note the error here in 3.4 docs (corrected later) -- it is actually PDC_DLL_BUILD, not PDCURSES_DLL_BUILD. Just to add to your confusion. :) (It's correct in e.g. the demo builds.)

Answer (score 0):

The last line of PDCurses' implementation of `initscr()` (really `Xinitscr()`, which is called by `initscr()`, but anyway) is simply `return stdscr;`. So there's absolutely no difference between `stdscr` and the return value of `initscr()`.

I don't know what you're doing wrong, but I can't reproduce any problem with your sample program. You might want to specify more about your environment -- OS, compiler, PDCurses version -- and exactly what it is that you're interpreting as a crash. BTW, the inclusion of stdio.h here is unnecessary (but harmless).

PDCurses doesn't support multiple simultaneous terminals, anyway.

Comment: Yes, there should be no difference, but it fails in my side. I am using Windows 8.1 x64, VC++ v18.00.31101 for x64 (from Visual Studio 2012), PDCurses v3.4.0.3 (downloaded with Nuget package manager). By crash I mean the program terminates unexpectedly with error.

And yes, `stdio.h` is not needed; I was making some tests with printf compiled for C++ and forgot to remove it, sorry.

Well, about the support of multiple terminals in PDCurses, the `newterm` function works perfectly on my side.